# Find the "n" largest elements in a Python 'list' with duplicate values

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list as shown:

```py
test= [19, 2, 8, 12, 8]
```

I sorted it as:

```py
print(sorted([(val, idx) for (idx, val) in enumerate(test)], reverse = True))
```

Output is:

```py
[(19, 0), (12, 3), (8, 4), (8, 2), (2, 1)]
```

I want to extract the first 4 largest numbers. Slicing will not work as I have duplicates in list (`8` at indices 2 and 4)

The output am expecting is:
(19, 0), (12, 3), (8, 4), (8, 2)

Is there any other way to get this done?

Comment: Then remove the duplicates before sorting?

Comment: The requirement is to include duplicates and get the max elements.

Comment: If you are allowed to use numpy, then maybe [np.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) is the way to go.

Comment: I believe my question was not properly framed. I will edit the question for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

To get four largest numbers from a list you can use:

```
sorted(sorted(set(test), key=test.index), reverse=True)[:4]
#[19, 12, 8, 2]
```

**EDIT**

This will give you the desired output:

```
[i[::-1] for i in sorted(enumerate(test), key=lambda x: x[::-1], reverse=True)][:4]
#[(19, 0), (12, 3), (8, 4), (8, 2)]
```

Comment: Slicing the list only fetched the top 4 values excluding the duplicate. I need to get the following:
(19, 0), (12, 3), (8, 4), (8, 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter to remove duplicates

```
from collections import Counter

test= [19, 2, 8, 12, 8, 1, 5, 6]
cnt = Counter(test)
print(sorted(cnt)[-4:]) #[6, 8, 12, 19]
```

Comment: I would like to retain the duplicates ad get the top value. Am not trying to count the # of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicates by transforming the list into a set, then go back to a list and sort the values. The code:

```
test= [19, 2, 8, 12, 8]

test_uniques_sorted = lsorted(list(set(test)), reverse = True)
print(test_uniques_sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test= [19, 2, 8, 12, 8]
n = 4
largestno = max(test)
nth_largest = (sorted(set(test),reverse = True)[n-1])
test_max = []
[test_max.append(n) for n in test  if n >= nth_largest and n <=largestno]     
print(sorted(test_max,reverse = True))
```